# Changing title in the same company under Blue Card

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have blue card, and I want to change my role within the same employer. Working hours, address, and salary are all same as well.
Do I need to get approval from Foreigners Office?

I haven't completed 2 years yet.

Berlin Foreigner Office says "it's not necessary if the name of your occupation changes, although the employment modalities continue
to correspond to those in the job description". What is meant by "modalities"?

Comment: It’s not a phrase I’d use (native English speaker) but I’d understand it to mean duties/responsibilities, working hours etc in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Getting promoted within a comnpany doesnt affect your current work permit. Only if you shift to a lower paid job or new employer within first two years - than you would need to apply for a new work permit. 
Modalities stands for working condistions of your work contract.
See details here: https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/dienstleistungen/service.245714.php/dienstleistung/326856/en/

Answer (score 1):

Modalities used this way will most probably mean salary and benefits. And these - as you've told us - haven't changed. So I would second David that you don't need to get approval. Nevertheless - just to make sure - you might nevertheless contact the foreigner office proactively to have them in the loop.